# Highlighting a Contour in SliceContourPlot3D

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

I've written the following code and it works well; however, I've tried (to no avail) to highlight in white the Log[5] contour inside the SliceContourPlot3D. My code is below. It works well separately. Can this be combined into the 3D plot? Ideas welcomed!

```
f[p_, x_] := p*Log[7] + (1 - p)*Log[x];
AA = Show[
  Plot3D[f[p, x], {p, 0, 1}, {x, 3, 7}, Mesh -> None, 
   PlotStyle -> Directive[Opacity[0.75], Specularity[White, 50]], 
   ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotTheme -> "Detailed", 
   FaceGrids -> None, 
   LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Arial", FontSize -> 12, Black}], 
  SliceContourPlot3D[f[p, x], 
   z == 1.1, {p, 0, 1}, {x, 3, 7}, {z, 0, 2}, 
   ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", Boxed -> False]]
BB = Show[
  ContourPlot[f[p, x], {p, 0, 1}, {x, 3, 7}, 
   ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"], 
  ContourPlot[f[p, x] == Log[5], {p, 0, 1}, {x, 3, 7}, 
   ContourStyle -> {Thick, White}]]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
highlight = 
  SliceContourPlot3D[f[p, x], 
   z == 1.1, {p, 0, 1}, {x, 3, 7}, {z, 0, 2}, 
   ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", Boxed -> False, Contours -> {Log[5]}, 
   ContourStyle -> Directive[AbsoluteThickness[5], White], 
   ContourShading -> None];
Show[AA, highlight]
```

[image]

Comment: nice! I seehow you have Contours->Log[5] here -- very nice!! ... thank u so much!

Answer (score 4):

Extract the automatically generated list of contour levels from `ContourPlot`

```
cl = Cases[ContourPlot[f[p, x], {p, 0, 1}, {x, 3, 7}], Tooltip[_, t_] :> t, All];
```

Append `cl` with desired contour levels and styles and use it as the option setting for `Contours` in `SliceContourPlot3D`:

```
SliceContourPlot3D[f[p, x], z == 1.1, {p, 0, 1}, {x, 3, 7}, {z, 0, 2}, 
 ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", Boxed -> False, 
 Contours -> Append[cl, {Log[5.], Directive[Thick, White]}]]
```

[image]

Comment: I like this view too as it provides a clear view of the height of the floor above zero, which you can control with z =1.1, or z= 1.5, etc. Thank you for sharing your skills kglr!!